# Cannot put Caption on a pseudocode of algorithm

Tags: algorithmic

I wrote an algorithm pseudocode using the **\userpackage{algorithmic}** and when i want to put a caption i get an error. This is the code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE $N\gets sizeof(\textit{input data})$\\
\textbf{Function} Twiddle(W, N, stuff)
\STATE $        W.r \gets cos(stuff.2.\Pi/N)$
\STATE $        W.i \gets -sin(stuff.2.\Pi/N)$\\
...
\IF{$N_{2}!=1$}
\STATE \textbf{Call} $radix-4(data[N_{2}.k1], N_{2})$
\ENDIF
\label{algo1}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{center}
```

Can someone help me on that and is there an alternative for this package that gives a better look.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `algorithmic` environment is not a floating environment, you have to use the `algorithm` wrapper environment. Note this environment cooperates with `caption`, so you can easily customise captions for this environment. Here is an example different from the default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
 \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmic}%

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}\captionsetup{labelfont={sc,bf}, labelsep=newline}
  \caption{Tweedledee and Tweedledum}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \STATE $N\gets sizeof(\textit{input data})$\\
    \textbf{Function} Twiddle(W, N, stuff)
    \STATE $ W.r \gets cos(stuff.2.\Pi/N)$
    \STATE $ W.i \gets -sin(stuff.2.\Pi/N)$\\
    ...
    \IF{$N_{2}!=1$}
    \STATE \textbf{Call} $radix-4(data[N_{2}.k1], N_{2})$
    \ENDIF
    \label{algo1}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `algorithm`-package, which defines a floattype for algorithms.

Hint: If you are using the `center`-environment, you are very likely doing something wrong.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
% algorithmic - Cannot put Caption on a pseudocode of algorithm - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange
% Url: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328108/cannot-put-caption-on-a-pseudocode-of-algorithm
% Date: mandag 5. september 2016 16.46.04


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}


 \begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \STATE $N\gets sizeof(\textit{input data})$\\
  \textbf{Function} Twiddle(W, N, stuff)
  \STATE $        W.r \gets cos(stuff.2.\Pi/N)$
  \STATE $        W.i \gets -sin(stuff.2.\Pi/N)$\\
  ...
  \IF{$N_{2}!=1$}
  \STATE \textbf{Call} $radix-4(data[N_{2}.k1], N_{2})$
  \ENDIF
  \label{algo1}
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Some awesome caption}
 \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be fixed by adding the `\renewcommand\thealgorithm{}` redefinition right after the `\begin{algorithm}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{}
\caption{A numberless algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE $N\gets sizeof(\textit{input data})$\\
\textbf{Function} Twiddle(W, N, stuff)
\STATE $        W.r \gets cos(stuff.2.\Pi/N)$
\STATE $        W.i \gets -sin(stuff.2.\Pi/N)$\\
...
\IF{$N_{2}!=1$}
\STATE \textbf{Call} $radix-4(data[N_{2}.k1], N_{2})$
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
\addtocounter{algorithm}{-1}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This only hides the numbering for the algorithm. I don't think the OP requested this. Other than that, your code works fine :)